# How to use the Worpress session outside folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel, wordpress

I am facing trouble to get the current user login detail in Laravel from WordPress

**My Directory Structure**

```
/public_html/
/public_html/ here is all Laravel files like app, route, resources etc. 
/public_html/shop/ here is the all WordPress Files
```

I was using the Service provider for load the wp-load.php files but when I call it its through me error i.e
`Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:851)`

**WordPressServiceProvider**

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Providers;
 
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use URL;
 
class WordPressServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
 
    /**
     * Path to our WP installation
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $bootstrapFilePath = '..\shop\wp-load.php';   
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        
        
        //echo 'SESSION => '.is_user_logged_in();
        /**
         * Here we can enqueue any extra scripts or styles we may need. 
         * I loaded my frontend specific styles and scripts that were of no use to the WP site
         */
        //wp_enqueue_style('frontend-styles', URL::asset('css/frontend.css'), ['dependencies'], false);
        //wp_enqueue_script('frontend-scripts', URL::asset('js/frontend.js'), ['dependencies'], false, true);
    }
 
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {   
        if(\File::exists($this->bootstrapFilePath)) {
            //echo 'INSIDE REGISTER';
            require_once($this->bootstrapFilePath);
        }else{
            //echo 'OUTSIDE REGISTER'.$this->bootstrapFilePath;         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out, it wil help you.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51080966/11241343)

Comment: The solution is not clear I tried it but not working. Where should I creat the helper and I am getting this error  "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in  wp-includes/l10n.php on line 288"